# Have DropDownListFor() save text to model instead of value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdownlist and the code for it is below. I'm trying to save the selected text to the model instead of the selected value but I can't seem to find documentation anywhere on how to do this. I'm brand new to mvc and getting through this learning curve has been frustrating for me. Thanks for any help!

View Code

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Urgency, "Urgency:")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Urgency, (SelectList)ViewBag.urgency, "--Select--", new { id = "urgencyList" })
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
// set the urgency list
        List<SelectListItem> urgency = new List<SelectListItem>();
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 Hours", Value = "42.9", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "12 Hours", Value = "39", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "24 Hours", Value = "33.8", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "48 Hours", Value = "28.6", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "3 Days", Value = "24.7", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "4 Days", Value = "22.75", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "5 Days", Value = "21.45", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 Days", Value = "19.95", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "7 Days", Value = "18.2", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "10 Days", Value = "14.95", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "20 Days", Value = "14.95", Selected = false });
        urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "30 Days", Value = "14.95", Selected = false });

        ViewBag.Urgency = new SelectList(urgency, "Value", "Text");
```

Model Code

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Urgency is Required.")]
    public string Urgency { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why do you put a value into the `SelectListItem` if you don't need it?

Comment: Make the `Value` property of the `SelectListItem` the same as the `Text`.e.g.  `urgency.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "6 Hours", Value = "6 Hours" });`. Note the `Selected` property is pointless since your binding to a model property (the value of the property determines what is selected)

Comment: @MotiAzu I need the value for something else but I need to send an email with the choices that they made and so because of that I need just the text

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't make them both the same because I need the value to perform a calculation

Comment: I suggest you save a mapping between these in a `Dictionary` so you will have the flexibility to get the value from the text and vice-versa.

Comment: Then you could use javascript to update a hidden field that's bound to another property on the the dropdown's change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a method to parse the text and return a value depending on which item it was